`hdfs dfs -rm` sends normal output to `stderr`?
For context :
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292

What I did :
$ hdfs dfs -rm -safely -r '/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10' 1>file1.log 2>file2.log

$ ls -l file*log
-rw-r--r-- 1 userName groupName   0 Oct 23 10:54 file1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 userName groupName 294 Oct 23 10:54 file2.log

⇒ nothing sent to stdout, but stderr got data
$ cat file2.log
24/10/23 10:58:19 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Moved: 'hdfs://HDFSROOT/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10' to trash at: hdfs://HDFSROOT/user/userName/.Trash/Current/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10

⇒ output that is not an error message has been sent to stderr : WHY ? I expected that output string to be sent to the file plugged to stdout : file1.log.
running the same command again on a missing file to cause an error :
$ hdfs dfs -rm -safely -r '/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10' 1>>file1.log 2>>file2.log
$ echo $?
1

$ ls -l file*log
-rw-r--r-- 1 userName groupName   0 Oct 23 10:58 file1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 userName groupName 411 Oct 23 10:59 file2.log

$ cat file2.log
24/10/23 10:58:19 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Moved: 'hdfs://HDFSROOT/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10' to trash at: hdfs://HDFSROOT/user/userName/.Trash/Current/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10
rm: `/path/to/data/year=2022/month=10': No such file or directory

⇒ the error message was appended to the file receiving stderr (as expected)
The documentation says :

Error information is sent to stderr and the output is sent to stdout.

What am I missing ?
